# Identifying non convex constraints

Tags: convex-analysis, non-convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem. I can figure that whether the objective function is concave or not w.r.t a certain variable by taking a 2nd derivative . If the second derivative is less than zero than it means that the objective function is concave. But how do I determine whether the constraints are convex or not . for example if I have constraint like this is this a convex constraint?
$alog_2(1+x)-a.b.c x => a.dlog_2(1+x)-b.x$

where a, b, c and d  are constants and I am considering the variable $x$

Comment: Please clarify your notation (what does “.” and $=>$ mean, use cdot if you want the multiplication dot)? Also, in 1d, the domain is either an interval or set of intervals - you can maximize within each interval as a convex set.

Comment: yes by .dot here I means multiplication

Comment: If a constraint can be expressed as $f(x) \leq 0$, where $f$ is a convex function, then it's a convex constraint. Boyd and Vandenberghe is a good book for learning to recognize convex optimization problems.

Comment: So if I can express a constraint as $f(x) \leq 0 $ and  the second derivative of $f(x)$ is also less than zero than it is convex constraint

Comment: If a smooth function is convex, its second derivative is nonnegative, not less than zero.

Comment: Looking at the second derivative is only one way to check if a function is convex. Many convex functions aren't differentiable, so they don't even have a second derivative. You should read some of Boyd and Vandenberghe.